# How to Install and Use Node Locally?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, remote-access

I am trying to run a React app that I built on my PC using create-react-app on a remote ssh server. However, when I do npm start on the remote server, I'm getting a "Module.createrequire is not a function", which I believe is because the node is outdated on the server. However, I can't update node because I don't have permissions (this is for a research project); is there any way to update node on the local folder (there's no nvm installed) or otherwise bypass this situation?

I've tried to update node globally but nvm isn't installed and I don't have permissions.

Comment: what was node version you used on the PC and what version are you using on a remote ssh server?

Comment: Node v10 on remote ssh, node 14 required that i was using on my pc

Answer (score 0):

Create React App

> Create React App is a comfortable environment for learning React, and
> is the best way to start building a new single-page application in
> React.
>
> It sets up your development environment so that you can use the latest
> JavaScript features, provides a nice developer experience, and
> optimizes your app for production. You’ll need to have Node >= 14.0.0
> and npm >= 5.6 on your machine.

So these are requirements that you must meet and it seems that it cannot be avoided that way .